# custom Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<TUser>

Tags: c#, async-await

I am a doing database-first project.

I spun up a new MVC5 site in VS2013.

I created an applicationUser that has an email property:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public String EMail { get; set; }
}
```

I then created an EMail field in the AspNetUsers table that had already been created.  I then created a domain specific user store that inherits from  Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore and I implemented two more functions:
FindByEmail and FindByEmailAsync.

The FindByEmail looks like this:

```
public ApplicationUser FindByEMail(String email)
{
    var context = base.Context;

    String commandText = "Select * from AspNetUsers Where EMail = @email";
    var query = context.Database.SqlQuery(typeof(ApplicationUser), commandText,new SqlParameter("@email",email));
    var result = query.ToListAsync().Result.ToArray().GetValue(0);
    return result as ApplicationUser;
}
```

My unit tests are running green with this method.  I am now trying to implement the async method and return a Task.  I am trying to do this without for..eaching though the Task and convering the objects to ApplicationUser.  The F# in my brain wants to do a Seq.Map(fun u -> (ApplicationUser)u a.  Is there an equiv for C#?

Am I even approaching the problem the correct way?  I am constrained and cannot follow MSDN's example because I cannot do code-first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, for the synchronous version, it would be better to avoid the async call in the first place.  You could write your query as:

```
var query = context.Database.SqlQuery<ApplicationUser>(commandText, new SqlParameter("@email",email));
return query.First();
```

This avoids wrapping "sync over async" (using `ToListAsync()` followed by the `Result` call).

For an async version, you'd just use:

```
public async Task<ApplicationUser> FindByEMailAsync(String email)
{
    var context = base.Context;

    String commandText = "Select * from AspNetUsers Where EMail = @email";
    var query = context.Database.SqlQuery<ApplicationUser>(commandText, new SqlParameter("@email",email));
    var data = await query.ToListAsync();
    return data.First();
}
```

---

On a side note:

> The F# in my brain wants to do a Seq.Map(fun u -> (ApplicationUser)u a. Is there an equiv for C#?

The equivelent C# would be to use `Enumerable.Select` via `a.Select(u => (ApplicationUser)u);`  That being said, using `a.Cast<ApplicationUser>().First()` would likely be more appropriate in this specific scenario.

Another side note:

These methods will be problematic if the email isn't found, since they assume you'll always get one matching result.  You could handle that by using `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` and `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `First`, and checking for the null response.  I purposefully did not write it this way, as I was trying to mimick the behavior of your original method (which will also throw, though yours throws an `IndexOutOfRangeException`, and mind would raise `InvalidOperationException`.)

Comment: I agree - I hadn't gotten there yet.  I have the non matching unit test already spun up....   I may not be interesting, but I always validate my arguments and always check my return values.   Cheap insurance.  8-)

Comment: It is dying on the first() and firstAsync().  'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).  I have a using System.Linq;

Comment: @JamieDixon Edited - I was thinking it was a normal `DbSet`, not a `DbRawSqlQuery` - the raw queries are not as nice in that respect.

Comment: @JamieDixon Also just switched to the generic method call, so you can eliminate the casts...  That should make `Enumerable.First<T>` work, as well.

Comment: I got it to compile using var data = await query.ToListAsync();
            return (ApplicationUser)data.FirstOrDefault();  Still think you need to have the cast...

Comment: @JamieDixon Did you change the `SqlQuery` line to what I have above (using the generic method)?  With that, the cast shouldn't be necessary.